# Is This an Appropriate Edit?

Tags: discussion

This edit popped up in the review queue and I’m not quite sure if my initial thought is correct or not:

[image: A Slippery Slope]

[The answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/86852/1222991) was posted almost a decade ago and — as you can see — has a very respectable upvote count. The question itself has been viewed almost six million times.

Looking at the edit, two things popped into my head:

1. The use of `apt-get` was standard in 2011
2. At no time did the person asking the question state they were having permission issues or that the file was downloaded to a directory not owned by the user account

If this edit is approved, then it would mean that we (the community) should go in an editing spree to clean up *all* references to `apt-get`, including those on new posts that are made today. This seems excessive. However, given that six million people have seen this question and a good percentage will have used this exact answer, an argument could be made that the edit is justified to ensure people are exposed to using `apt` without `-get` before the deprecated command is removed.

Am I just overthinking this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`apt-get` is not deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829864/is-apt-get-deprecated). The additional command seems unnecessary. I would reject this edit with a custom message saying that `apt-get` is not deprecated. It would also make sense to reject it as "no improvement".

If you feel like the additional command adds value, you could approve the edit (changing `apt-get` to `apt` is not a problem, just not needed) - that would also be reasonable in my opinion.